# Backup mySQL tables, but only if changed since last backup?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a little script that will backup tables into separate .SQL files on a nightly cron. So far I have this, and it works well:

**db-backup.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASES=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -hlocalhost -uroot -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database)

for db in $DATABASES; do

    DIR=/backup/mysql/$db

    [ -n "$DIR" ] || DIR=.
    test -d $DIR || mkdir -p $DIR

    echo "Dumping tables into separate SQL command files for database '$db' into dir=$DIR"

    tbl_count=0

    for t in $(mysql --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -uroot -D $db -NBA -e 'show tables')
    do
        echo "DUMPING TABLE: $db.$t"
        mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -uroot $db $t | gzip > $DIR/$db.$t.sql.gz
        tbl_count=$(( tbl_count + 1 ))
    done

    echo "$tbl_count tables dumped from database '$db' into dir=$DIR"

done
```

This works like a charm, and backs up all the tables into smaller files, compressed. The reason I want to do this, is that some tables will change, but lots of them will remain the same (some of them quite large tables - 10+gb).

I'm trying to work out if I can make it so the MySQL dump ONLY happens if it has had a change since the last backup?

Comment: Don't forget --routines and other things that are not included in the dump that you are doing.

Comment: @RickJames interesting - what does `--routines` do? I don't think I've used them before. Does Wordpress,. and other systems use them?

Comment: I don't know if WP uses any Stored Procedures, Stored Functions, Triggers, etc.  Some of them are specific to a database, not a table, hence a separate mysqldump is needed.

Comment: @RickJames ah ok. I've added it in now anyway, as well as --add-drop-table, which I've just realised I was missing: `mysqldump --add-drop-table --routines --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -uroot $db $t | gzip > $DIR/$db.$t.sql.gz`. TBH most of these DBs are just my own stuff - so I should know what is in them. But I agree, for some people it may be more important :)

Comment: @RickJames - how do you dump just those DB specific routines? I wonder if its worth adding in a dump that does just that (no table structure, just functions that are specific to the DB)

Comment: That's what I do in my Perl script that is similar to your shell script.  When there are no routines in a DB, the dump is empty (except for some boilerplate); no harm is done.

Comment: PS:  dba.stackoverflow.com is a better forum for database admin discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to answer my own question. I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASES=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -hlocalhost -uroot -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database)

for db in $DATABASES; do

    if [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" && "$db" != "information_schema" && "$db" != "mysql"  ]]; then

        DIR=/backup/mysql/$db

        [ -n "$DIR" ] || DIR=.
        test -d $DIR || mkdir -p $DIR

        echo "Dumping tables into separate SQL command files for database '$db' into dir=$DIR"

        tbl_count=0

        for t in $(mysql --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf -uroot -D $db -NBA -e 'show tables');
        do
            echo "DUMPING TABLE: $db.$t"

            # detect which type of DB we are using - myISAM or Innodb
            if test -f "/var/lib/mysql/$db/$t.MYI"; then
                #echo "its myi"
                last_modified=$(stat -c %y "/var/lib/mysql/$db/$t.MYI")
            else
                #echo "its ibd"
                last_modified=$(stat -c %y "/var/lib/mysql/$db/$t.ibd")
            fi

            # see if we have a mod timestamp for this...
            if test -f "$DIR/$t.mod"; then
                value=$(<$DIR/$t.mod)
            else
                value=0
            fi

            echo "  LAST MOD: $last_modified"

            if [ "$value" != "$last_modified" ]; then

                echo "  Seems like this one has changed... '$value' != '$last_modified' ";

                # make sure we update the modified timestamp
                echo $last_modified > $DIR/$t.mod

                # doing dump now...
                mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf --add-drop-table --routines -uroot $db $t | gzip > $DIR/$db.$t.sql.gz

                # write down the tables that are changed...
                tbl_count=$(( tbl_count + 1 ))

            else

                echo "  Not changed since last dump on $last_modified"

            fi

        done

        echo "$tbl_count tables dumped from database '$db' into dir=$DIR"
    else
        echo "SKIP DB: $db "
    fi

done
```

It will skip the performance_schema, information_schema and MySQL DB's as I don't care about those. It will then set a `.mod` file for each table once it dumps it. This is then read next time the script runs, and if its not changed since then, it won't bother to re-dump the table. It relies on having the root MySQL logins set in `/root/.my.cnf`, like so:

```
[client]
password='xxxx'
```

This means you can do passwordless with the script (instead of revealing it in the process list)